# Append a custom key => value to a document obtained from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem that is probably very simple for you, but it is driving me crazy.

I need to add a custom key => value to a document obtained from Firestore, but I don't know how. I leave you the code and you take a look:

```
  Map<String, Object> appendThis = new HashMap<>();

  ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("followers");

  if(list.contains(userId)) {
        appendThis.put("switch_status", true);
  } else {
        appendThis.put("switch_status", false);
  }

  /* I need to merge appendThis to document.toObject here, before the .add!! But how? */

  choices.add(document.toObject(Choice.class));
```

Thanks, I don't know what I would do without you!

Comment: If you are trying to update fields of a document, there is documentation for that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Comment: No, I don't want to update the document in the db, I want to modify the document before the .toObject

Comment: Sorry, it's not really clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: I receive the document with sample data like `{a:1, b:2, c:3}` but my Choice.class has also `d` attribute, so I need to add `d` attribute (in my example `d` is `switch_status`) before calling my class

Comment: document = `{a:1, b:2, c:3}`  |  
appendThis = `{switch_status: true}`  |  
whatWeNeed = document + appendThis = `{a:1, b:2, c:3, switch_status: true}`

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to modify the Choice object after toObject is called but before you add it to the list.

Comment: If you could advise or guide me with an example I would be very grateful! I think I should focus it on the line that you comment